# Requiring unknown module ./bindings on react native

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native

I'm trying to run my react-native project on android but when I try to execute it I get the following error on the android simulator:

> "Requiering unknown module ./bindings. If you are sure the module is
>   there, try restarting the packager or running npm install"

The thing is that I have checked up node_modules and I can see that the module is there. I have already tried to remove node_modules and install all of them again but didn't work.

I have also tried to install bindings with npm install bindings and I get the following error:

> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency
>   /noble/bluetooth-hci-socket:
>
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or
>   architecture: bluetooth-hci-socket@0.4.4

I'm on MACOS

Comment: could you please post your some code here.